# Fetch Weekend date from a date column using spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to get the weekend day ( Saturdays date ) from a date column using spark SQL .

For e.g

If i provide a date "2020-01-10" it should return "2020-01-11"
If i provide a date "2020-01-01" it should return "2020-01-04"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using

```sql
cast(date_add(date_Column, 6-cast(date_format(date_Column, 'u') as BIGINT)) as date) weekend_day
```

Answer (score 2):

From Spark 2.3.0 you can use `date_trunc` to get beginning of week date, and then add number of days to get to desired week day.

```
spark.sql("select '2020-01-10' given, date_trunc('WEEK', '2020-01-10') week_start , date_add(date_trunc('WEEK', '2020-01-10'),5) saturday_date").show()
+----------+-------------------+-------------+
|     given|         week_start|saturday_date|
+----------+-------------------+-------------+
|2020-01-10|2020-01-06 00:00:00|   2020-01-11|
+----------+-------------------+-------------+
```